# How to make color coded chats between client and server using JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I have a simple client-server chat system that I want to colour code so that messages from the client and messages fom the server get displayed in different colors. I have the following:

```
       try {
            String messageout="";
           messageout=jTextField1.getText();
           jTextField1.setText("");

        appendToPane(jTextPane1,"\n"+"client: "+messageout,Color.BLUE);
        dos.writeUTF(messageout);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

dos is the data output stream

and:

```
private void appendToPane(JTextPane tp, String msg, Color c)
{
    StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
    AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, c);

    aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.FontFamily, "Lucida Console");
    aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.Alignment, StyleConstants.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);

    int len =tp.getDocument().getLength();
    tp.setCaretPosition(len);
    tp.setCharacterAttributes(aset, false);
    tp.replaceSelection(msg);
    tp.setText(tp.getText()+msg);
```

}

The server has simlar code that sets the color to green rather than blue. The problem is I want that client messages to be displayed in blue and the server messages to be displayed in green, whereas at the moment, in the client, all messages are being displayed in blue and in the server all messages are being displayed in green. I want the following:
'client:blaablaa(in blue)'
'server:blaablaa(in green)'

Is anybody able to help?

EDIT: Client reading from server (color removed till I find real solution)

```
        s=new Socket("localhost",1000);
        dis=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        dos=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        while(!msgin.equals("bye")){
            msgin=dis.readUTF();
           jTextPane1.setText(jTextPane1.getText()+"\n"+"server:"+msgin);
```

I want to add color context to the last line of code.

EdIT - using appendToPane rather than setText(nothing being displayed, when I remove the last setText from appendToPane:

```
    ss = new ServerSocket(1000);
    s = ss.accept();
    dis=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    dos=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    while(!msgin.equals("bye")){
        msgin=dis.readUTF();
         appendToPane(jTextPane1,"\n"+"client: "+msgin,Color.RED);
```

AND:

```
        String messageout="";
        messageout=jTextField1.getText();


    jTextField1.setText("");
     appendToPane(jTextPane1,"\n"+"server:"+messageout,Color.BLUE);
     //jTextPane1.setText(jTextPane1.getText()+"\n"+"server:"+messageout);
        dos.writeUTF(messageout);
```

Comment: Pass the color with the message?

Comment: Where is the part where you add the server's messages to your client's `JTextPane`?

Comment: @RealSkeptic. Code added. Color removed until I find solution. Gilbert Le Blanc - that is exactly the question. How can I add color to the messages coming in from server/client

Comment: I notice that your `addToPane` displays every message twice. Why do you have the `tp.setText(tp.getText()+msg)` at the end? Without it your method seems to work fine and allow different colors for different parts of the text.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Without it, nothing gets displayed in the TextPane for some reason. Can you think why?

Comment: No, it displays quite well for me. That's why I said it displays every message twice. How is your text pane declared and initialized?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I created it through drag and drop in netbeans. I will edit question using addToPane rather than setText. I would be v grateful if you could work out what is going on. Thank you

Comment: @RealSkeptic Additional code added to question. Apologies its from the server not the client, but same idea

Comment: You should use or myJtextPane.getDocument().insertString, or myJTextPane.setInputAttribute+myJTextPane.getEditorKit.read to insert styled text to your jtextPane

Comment: I suppose your text pane is set to be not editable?

Comment: @Sharcoux in the context of client-server, how do I do this. I want to style the text as I write out the stream(dos.writeUTF) or readIn from data input stream. Do you mind providing example based on code I have above

Comment: @RealSkeptic thats right but I don't really want the chat window to be editable if possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `TextPane` is set to be not editable (e.g., you have a `tp.setEditable(false)` somewhere, then you cannot use operations that edit it. The method `replaceSelection()` is an editing method, and thus, instead of doing anything, it just beeps.

So you have opted to replace the entire text of the text pane, which is not considered an editing method. But then, you lose the styling.

Instead of doing either, in a non-editable text pane, you should add to the document that backs the text pane. So, for example, change your `appendToPane` like this:

```
private static void appendToPane(JTextPane tp, String msg, Color c)
{
    StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
    AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, c);

    aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.FontFamily, "Lucida Console");
    aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.Alignment, StyleConstants.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);

    // Get the TextPane's Document
    Document doc = tp.getDocument();
    int len = doc.getLength();
    try {
        doc.insertString(len, msg, aset);  // Use the `insertString` method of the document.
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        // Nothing. Using the doc length makes sure this exception isn't thrown
    }

}
```

Comment: I am no longer skeptical of you ;). Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

You can [embed basic HTML](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html) with your Swing components.

```
b1 = new JButton("<html><center><b><u>D</u>isable</b><br>"
                 + "<font color=#ffffdd>middle button</font>",
                 leftButtonIcon);
Font font = b1.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN);
b1.setFont(font);
...
b2 = new JButton("middle button", middleButtonIcon);
b2.setFont(font);
b2.setForeground(new Color(0xffffdd));
...
b3 = new JButton("<html><center><b><u>E</u>nable</b><br>"
                 + "<font color=#ffffdd>middle button</font>",
                 rightButtonIcon);
b3.setFont(font);
```

*Code taken from the linked page.*

Comment: I don't want to to add HTML to a button or a component itself. I want to add it in text within a component